# Translate html snippet from A to B

Tags: html, regex, text

I am using microsoft word, filtered html to create website content. For good reason (word changes images), I want to specify the correct image paths on my site. Each image has an associated hyperlink (placed in word file) to the correct image path. Word does not appear to have the ability to set real filenames for image source, preferring to place the images in a separate directory with different image names. Damn windoze and word, too useful to avoid.

I need a bash script (not sure appropriate tool) to convert strings within a file $1:

src=".*_files/.*" to src="match from previous href="/SecureOffice_Images/.*""
where .* is wildcard

Example Input

```
<p class=MsoNormal align=center style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
text-align:center'><span lang=EN-CA><a
href="/SecureOffice_Images/PuTTY_Login_Prompt.jpg"><span style='color:windowtext;
text-decoration:none'><img border=0 width=391 height=80 id="Picture 2"
src="Tools_files/image002.jpg"></span></a></span></p>
```

Example Output:

```
<p class=MsoNormal align=center style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
text-align:center'><span lang=EN-CA><a
href="/SecureOffice_Images/PuTTY_Login_Prompt.jpg"><span style='color:windowtext;
text-decoration:none'><img border=0 width=391 height=80 id="Picture 2"
src="/SecureOffice_Images/PuTTY_Login_Prompt.jpg"></span></a></span></p>
```

`src="Tools_files/image002.jpg"` has been replaced by `src="/SecureOffice_Images/PuTTY_Login_Prompt.jpg"`

in other words, the "src=" value is replaced by the previous "href=" value between the `<p> </p>` tags

Anyone have tool / code suggestions? Script will run on linux.

Thanks;
Bill

Comment: Basically your task asks for a parser to produce a tree representation sporting an API that allows to modify the hierarchy. One approach would be to build the DOM from the html and use JS. Another idea is to turn the html into syntactically valid xml (ie. xhtml) using a linter like `xmllint` or `xmlstarlet`, followed by running a xslt stylesheet to transform the html according to your specs. The quick & dirty (and eventually very painful) path would lead you into the realm of regular expressions. Best option depends on your tech stack, skills, and whether this is a one-time task.

Comment: Word treats hyperlinks to paths correctly when you have a website image in a root path on the hard drive. For example, highlighting some text and creating a hyperlink gets this  `directory/screenshot.jpg` where _directory_ is the path from the root of your actual website file structure.

Comment: issue not hyperlink path (which I can set correctly), it is img src= path

Comment: its a every time update site, not one time task, many affected files.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @collapsar

You got me thinking that my image link methodology requires too much work / complexity due to the link being a separate element requiring building an element tree and doing inter-element multi-line search + replace, so I looked to simplifying the problem (creation of my own methodology).

New approach: Do not use link fields to specify REAL image path, use the "alt=" field, which will appear on same line as "src=" field, wheras "href=" may not (introducing the complexity).

New Input:

```
<p class=MsoNormal align=center style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
text-align:center'><span lang=EN-CA><img border=0 width=429 height=409
id="Picture 19" src="Tools_files/image001.jpg"
alt="/SecureOffice_Images/PuTTY_Login.jpg"></span></p>
```

New Output:

```
<p class=MsoNormal align=center style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
text-align:center'><span lang=EN-CA><img border=0 width=429 height=409
id="Picture 19" 
src="/SecureOffice_Images/PuTTY_Login.jpg"></span></p>
```

Translation Alg:

```
perl -pi -e 's|src=".*?"||g' $1
sed -i 's/alt=/src=/g' $1
```

I attempted (prefer) sed over perl, but could not get around greediness:
`sed -i 's/src=".*?"//g' $1` (Q - possible with sed?)

So now, I have a way to automatically go from MS Word filtered html to what my site requires. For now, run the translation script manually. Ultimately, integrate it with my pre-rendering automatic TOC and popup creation scripts.

FYI: here's the site: www.rossco.org

Regards;
Bill